# Binding dynamically using ng-repeat to check box data model

Tags: html, angularjs

I am really new angular and I have been struggling with this issue all day long. I am trying to add check boxes dynamically to my html page using ng-repeat and bind their ng-data-model.
Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script>
(function(angular) {
var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", []);
    helloApp.controller("HelloCtrl", ['$scope',function($scope) {

            $scope.legsDurations = {};
           var amountOfLegs = 3;
            for(var k = 1; k <= amountOfLegs; k++) {
                $scope.legsDurations[k] = {
                    disabled: true
               };
 }

}]);
})(window.angular);

</script>

</head>
<body ng-app="helloApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="value in legsDurations">
 <input  ng-data-model="value.disabled"  type="checkbox" >
{{value.disabled}}
</div>
            </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-data-model` is wrong. Use `ng-model` or `data-ng-model`

```
...
<input ng-model="value.disabled" type="checkbox">
...
```

**Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script>
(function(angular) {
var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", []);
    helloApp.controller("HelloCtrl", ['$scope',function($scope) {

            $scope.legsDurations = {};
           var amountOfLegs = 3;
            for(var k = 1; k <= amountOfLegs; k++) {
                $scope.legsDurations[k] = {
                    disabled: true
               };
 }

}]);
})(window.angular);

</script>

</head>
<body ng-app="helloApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="value in legsDurations">
 <input  ng-model="value.disabled"  type="checkbox" >
{{value.disabled}}
</div>
            </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !